# Combination of implicit conversion, equality operator and nullables fails to compile after update from Visual Studio 2015.2 to 2015.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Below code compiles in VS2015.2, but after upgrade to VS2015.3 it fails with `error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Registration<Something>' and 'Something'`.

```
  public class Class1
  {
      public Class1()
      {
          var a = new Registration<Something>();
          var x = a == Something.Bad; // this line fails in VS2015.3
      }
  }

  public struct Registration<T> where T:struct
  {
      public static implicit operator T?(Registration<T> registration)
      {
          return null;
      }
  }

  public enum Something
  {
      Good,
      Bad
  }
```

I can not find any notice about such a change in the changelog for update 3. Can someone tell me, why this happens? And which is the correct behavior?

EDIT: Combination of implicit conversion, equality operator and nullables... and enums. This only seems to fail when T is an enum.

Comment: `a == (Something?)Something.Bad` seems to work, don't know why this changed.... and R# of course complains about this unnecessary cast...

Comment: Yes, it works with a cast. And it actually works with an explicit conversion on the left side too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug. We're tracking this as https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13380